# Struts 2 annotation error when calling action

Tags: java, spring, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin, action-mapping

Hi all I'm having problems using Struts 2 Annotated Actions

**In my `pom.xml` I have:**

```
<!-- STRUTS2 annotation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.16.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- STRUTS2 SPRING integration -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**in my `web.xml`:**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.agiletec.apsadmin.system.dispatcher.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>        
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>struts.objectFactory</param-name>
      <param-value>spring</param-value>        
      </init-param>        
<init-param>
    <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
    <param-value>it.aicof.projects.openMED.aps.internalservlet.actions</param-value>
</init-param>          
</filter>  
  
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/do/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**I have two action classes:**

```
@Namespace("/budget")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BudgetAction extends BaseAction {
    
    @Action(value = "/start", results = { @Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/openmed/aps/jsp/internalservlet/budget/budget.jsp") })
    public String start(){
.......


@Namespace("/upload")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UploadAction extends BaseAction {

    @Action(value = "/init", results = {
        @Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/openmed/aps/jsp/internalservlet/upload/upload.jsp")})
    public String init() {
        .....
```

if I call the first one `http://localhost:8080/openMED/do/budget/start.action` all works
but when I call the second one `http://localhost:8080/openMED/do/upload/init.action` i get this error

```
 There is no Action mapped for namespace [/do] and action name [init] associated with context path [/openMED]. - [unknown location]

    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What's wrong? Two classes are configured in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message

> 2014-07-18 15:49:15,454 - ERROR - Dispatcher - Exception occurred during processing request: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/do] and action name [init] associated with context path [/openMED]. - [unknown location].

you have used url `/openMED/do/upload/init.action` but your action is mapped to the namespace `/upload`. A namespace is a path from the context path to action name. You can find more information about [namespace configuration](http://struts.apache.org/docs/namespace-configuration.html). You can also look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-namespace-configuration-example-and-explanation) example to better understand namespaces concept.

You should change action mapping

```
@Namespace("/do/upload")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UploadAction extends BaseAction {

@Action(value = "init", results = {@Result(name = "success", location = "/WEB-INF/openmed/aps/jsp/internalservlet/upload/upload.jsp")})
public String init() {
```

Comment: Roman.. i realized the problem was not i was thinking to... so i change the question to try to be more specific

Comment: Updated to you changes.

Comment: ok but the other one is /openMED/do/budget/start.action same pattern as /openMED/do/upload/init.action .... and it works correctly.
So.. why the first one works and the other one not?

Comment: You might have other action mapping. You didn't post `struts.xml`.

Comment: i have not a struts.xml.... maybe i found the problem, it was my mistake. i mapped actions path in web.xml as `it.aicof.projects.openMED.aps.internalservlet.actions` but the action not working was in path `it.aicof.projects.openMED.aps.internalservlet` so it was not recognized as action by struts. I'll try to move it in the right path